# OpenCart 3 error using PayPal

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I have setup OpenCart 3 here www.toolfolks.com/shop

When I add this product for a test http://toolfolks.com/shop/index.php?rou ... 7&search=£ (it is only 10 pence ) I can purchase from a mobile device but a web browser fails.
I see the following in the console:

```
logger.js:53 ppxo_paypal_legacy_component_error Object {error: "Error:         Unexpected init message from domain https:/…ects.com/api/checkout.js?_=1500727174949:2414:13)", timestamp: 1500727199320, windowID: "8145ed1bca", pageID: "70cfa4e30c", referer: "toolfolks.com"…} 

Error: Unexpected init message from domain https://www.paypal.com -- expected message from https://www.sandbox.paypal.com
at Object.handler (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/check ... 49:3563:41)
at https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/check ... 49:2464:32
at Function.ZalgoPromise.try (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/check ... 49:7735:37)
at Object._RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.(anonymous function) [as postrobot_message_request] (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/check ... 49:2460:70)
at receiveMessage (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/check ... 49:2393:77)
at messageListener (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/check ... 49:2414:13)
print @ logger.js:53
log @ logger.js:161
error @ logger.js:188
(anonymous) @ interface.js:240
(anonymous) @ util.js:50
(anonymous) @ promise.js:158
ZalgoPromise.dispatch @ promise.js:183
ZalgoPromise.reject @ promise.js:111
(anonymous) @ promise.js:153
ZalgoPromise.dispatch @ promise.js:183
ZalgoPromise.reject @ promise.js:111
(anonymous) @ promise.js:179
(anonymous) @ promise.js:158
ZalgoPromise.dispatch @ promise.js:183
ZalgoPromise.reject @ promise.js:111
(anonymous) @ index.js:1176
ZalgoPromise.try @ promise.js:291
ParentComponent.error @ index.js:1175
ZalgoPromise.try @ promise.js:291
error:promisified @ decorators.js:25
(anonymous) @ base.js:184
(anonymous) @ types.js:65
ZalgoPromise.try @ promise.js:291
_RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.(anonymous function) @ types.js:53
receiveMessage @ index.js:112
messageListener @ index.js:138
logger.js:53 ppxo_paypal_legacy_render_error_hijack_revert_target     Object {timestamp: 1500727199339, windowID: "8145ed1bca", pageID: "70cfa4e30c", referer: "toolfolks.com", host: "toolfolks.com"…}
print @ logger.js:53
log @ logger.js:161
warn @ logger.js:184
(anonymous) @ interface.js:243
(anonymous) @ util.js:50
(anonymous) @ promise.js:158
ZalgoPromise.dispatch @ promise.js:183
ZalgoPromise.reject @ promise.js:111
(anonymous) @ promise.js:153
ZalgoPromise.dispatch @ promise.js:183
ZalgoPromise.reject @ promise.js:111
(anonymous) @ promise.js:179
(anonymous) @ promise.js:158
ZalgoPromise.dispatch @ promise.js:183
ZalgoPromise.reject @ promise.js:111
(anonymous) @ index.js:1176
ZalgoPromise.try @ promise.js:291
ParentComponent.error @ index.js:1175
ZalgoPromise.try @ promise.js:291
error:promisified @ decorators.js:25
(anonymous) @ base.js:184
(anonymous) @ types.js:65
ZalgoPromise.try @ promise.js:291
_RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.(anonymous function) @ types.js:53
receiveMessage @ index.js:112
messageListener @ index.js:138
```

I have enabled Debug logging but don't know where any log files go ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you check system/storage/logs/error.log ?

Comment: The error.log is blank.

Comment: Also on a browser if I right click the payment button and open in a new window I can make the transaction.